# Error inflating class com.google.android.ads.AdView

Tags: android, admob

I've got quite weird problem with new AdView creation in layout XML while migrating from old AdMob.

OK.
Product target- Google API 19
Default properties- Google API 8

google play lib is referenced in the project and seems to be dexed and then included into resulting apk (proof is below).

I have the following code in my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0"
android:orientation="vertical" >
...
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"
    />
```

When I load the layout I've got the exception.

I see the following suspicious things:

1. I have specially put code which uses AdView BEFORE the XML loading and have no exception there

   ```
   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView ad= new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(this);

   try
   {
   setContentView(R.layout.ap_map);
   }
   catch(RuntimeException e)

   {
       throw e;

   }
   ```

So, I assume that there is no prob with google play library inclusion itself.
However, when I debugged the exception- I've got an internal exception- NoClassDefFoundException, so it looks exactly like I have google play lib missed

1. I have weird probs with AdView declaration- if I declare it as google suggest

I've got an error saying that

```
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package MYPACKAGE
```

So I had to add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
```

in the top of the layout declaration to get rid of this

Any ideas? I've read a few related topics here and all of them seems to be related with google play lib absence but it does not seem to be the case

Comment: My more experienced colleague found an answer. Probably will be helpful- so I won't remove the question. As I guessed the prob was related to XML itself- the right way is to add res-auto as google says BUT import google play library properly onto workspace and then refer it in the library list (known problem as well). After that the adview class become visible!

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
```

to:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```